# Sort array keys by date

Tags: php

How can I sort this array by the date using the keys

```
Array
(
    [Jun '12] => 2037
    [May '12] => 4615
    [Apr '12] => 4175
    [Mar '12] => 4548
    [Feb '12] => 2758
    [Jan '12] => 3077
    [Jul '12] => 0
)
```

I tried uksort with this callback function with no such luck.

```
function datediff($a, $b) {
     strtotime($a);
    $a = date('U',strtotime($a));
    $b = date('U',strtotime($b));

    if ($a == $b) $r = 0;
    else $r = ($a > $b) ? 1: -1;

    return $r;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to your datediff() function without uksort? Does it return the correct value for different $a,$b? Have you tried if the call to date() returns what you expect?

Comment: your strtotime isn't working with the keys provided.

Comment: As I can see, PHP does not support this date format: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom mapping

```
$date_map = array("Jan" => 1, "Feb" => 2, "Mar" => 3, "Apr" => 4, "May" => 5, "Jun" => 6, "Jul" => 7, "Aug" => 8, "Sep" => 9, "Oct" => 10, "Nov" => 11, "Dec" => 12);

function date_compare($a, $b) {
  global $date_map;

  $a_month = $date_map[substr($a, 0, 3)];
  $b_month = $date_map[substr($b, 0, 3)];

  if ($a_month == $b_month) return 0;
  return ($a_month > $b_month) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

The use date_compare with uksort

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the ' in your keys with "20"

http://codepad.org/sNv9QRtg

This should be a working example with some test code.

```
$values = array
(
    "Jun '12" => 2037,
    "May '12" => 4615,
    "Apr '12" => 4175,
    "Mar '12" => 4548,
    "Feb '12" => 2758,
    "Jan '12" => 3077,
    "Jul '12" => 0
);

//I tried uksort with this callback function with no such luck.

function datediff($a, $b) {
     strtotime($a);
    $a = date('U',strtotime(str_replace("'", "20", $a)));
    $b = date('U',strtotime(str_replace("'", "20", $b)));

    if ($a == $b) $r = 0;
    else $r = ($a > $b) ? 1: -1;

    return $r;
}

foreach($values as $key=>$val) {
    echo $key . " = " . strtotime(str_replace("'", "20", $key)) . "\n";
}

// before
print_r($values);

uksort($values, "datediff");

// after
print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

**datediff()** always returns **0** because **strtotime()** does not understand the single quote in front of the 12. Thus, $a and $b are empty (and therefore equal).

So if possible you should use something like "Mar 12" as your key instead of "Mar '12". Otherwise you will have to add some sort of string manipulation in **datediff** before calling **strtotime()**.